# C++ get start of this current year in unixtime

Tags: c++, date, unix-timestamp

I'm looking for a way to retrieve the start of the current year as a unix timestamp.

For example if we're on 2017-10-16 the unix timestamp is 1523318400. I have to retrieve 1483228800 (2017-01-01) instead. And it must work for the next years too of course.

Comment: It's pretty easy to [calculate](https://www.unixtimestamp.com/). All necessary hints are at the link.

Comment: i need to calculate it with c++

Comment: Get the current year. Then create a time with `year = current year, month = 1, day = 1, hour = 0, minute = 0, seconds = 0`.

Comment: @Barmar could you show me an example with a code snippet? please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions to add and subtract a number of months, days, minutes and seconds from a time_t, which can be used to calculate the the time_t for a point in the past, but it looks quite awkward to find the correct number of units to remove. ([cpp reference : time_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point)).  I also looked at original C function [mktime](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/mktime/).  However, whilst creating a time_t and then a struct tm*, the issue is correctly generating a timezone correct version.

So my solution is something like this....

```
int getYear(time_t now)
{
    struct tm * tnow = std::gmtime(&now);
    return tnow->tm_year + 1900;
}

std::time_t calculateYear( int currentYear )
{
     int epochYear = currentYear - 1970;
     int leapYears = (epochYear + 1) / 4;
     time_t result = epochYear * 24 * 60 * 60 * 365;
     result += leapYears * 24 * 60 * 60;
     return result;
}
```

The code is good for years between 1970 (first time_t value) and 2100, which is not a leap year from a 100 year rule.

The number of leap years is strange, as whilst 2012 is a leap year, it is 2013 which is the first year beginning to count it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source C++11/14/17 date/time library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/date.html).  It would be as simple as this:

```
#include "date/date.h"

date::sys_seconds
start_of_year(date::sys_seconds t)
{
    using namespace date;
    return sys_days{year_month_day{floor<days>(t)}.year()/jan/1};
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    std::cout << start_of_year(date::sys_seconds{1523318400s}) << '\n';
}
```

This outputs:

```
1514764800s
```

Note that this is not the answer you said you wanted.  However it is correct.  You can debug this discrepancy with this library as well:

```
std::cout << date::sys_seconds{1523318400s} << '\n';
```

This outputs:

```
2018-04-10 00:00:00
```

instead of `2017-10-16`.  You can find the Unix Time stamp for `2017-10-16` with:

```
using namespace date::literals;
std::cout << date::sys_seconds{date::sys_days{2017_y/10/16}}.time_since_epoch() << '\n';
```

which outputs:

```
1508112000s
```

And:

```
std::cout << start_of_year(date::sys_seconds{1508112000s}).time_since_epoch() << '\n';
```

will output:

```
1483228800s
```

You can also use this library to find the current year:

```
date::year
current_year()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return year_month_day{floor<days>(system_clock::now())}.year();
}
```

And you could rewrite (or overload) `start_of_year` to take a `date::year` instead of (or in addition to) `date::sys_seconds`:

```
date::sys_seconds
start_of_year(date::year y)
{
    using namespace date;
    return sys_days{y/jan/1};
}
```

And now you can write:

```
int
main()
{
    using date::operator<<;
    std::cout << start_of_year(current_year()).time_since_epoch() << '\n';
}
```

which currently outputs:

```
1483228800s
```